# How to remove jdbc request result column name in variable

Tags: jmeter

I have stored jdbc request result in variable and I'm using this variable in different http request.

Result is:

> Column name: code
> Result value: XI066270

variable passed as `[{code=XI066270}]`

How to remove column name and only pass value in variable?

I'm expecting to pass only value i.e. `XI066270`.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler documentation:

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is A,,C, then the following variables will be set up:
>
> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> C_#=2 (number of rows)
> C_1=column 3, row 1
> C_2=column 3, row 2
> ```

So if your JDBC Request looks like:

[image]

you should be able to refer the first row as `${code_1}`, second row (if exists) as `${code_2}`, etc.

More information: [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it worked perfectly. thanks once again